# Library with custom URL for each item based upon imported filename and/or property

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, picture-library

**Background:** 
I'm implementing an online org chart which needs to include the employees photo. We have a blend of online users that exist in the HR database + Active Directory, and offline users who are only in the HR Database. For this reason the User Profile Service is out. The software selected (TeamImprover Org Chart App) will present employee photos when the DataSource has a link to an imagine. Employee information is stored in a HR Database, and the source for the org chart is an SQL query. Each employee has a unique ID number.

**Proposed Solution** 
I'm considering the use of a SharePoint Library to host the images. New employees would be added to the library when they are hired. For example, an employee would be hired and assigned employee number '10123' in the HR database, we would upload a photo called 10123.jpg to the library. The org chart application (which uses a direct feed from the HR Database) would then reference that image such as https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/EmpPhoto/10123.jpg

**Problem/Request** 
The URL sucks. Instead of something friendly, it creates a long URL with some horrific ID. In all my searching, I am unable to find an easy solution. I have two main requirements:
1. That the URL created has a predictable pattern, with the employee number being the only thing that changes between different library items.
2. That the custom URL is created automatically.

Any insights or search suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so 5 minutes after posting the question I worked out the answer.

The horrible URL that is created is only a reference to the display form. The underlying image is created with the original filename.

So for example when I load 10123.jpg into the library at https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/EmpPhoto/,  the resulting URL is https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/EmpPhoto/10123.jpg

Probably explains why I couldn't find any sources regarding this - it does exactly what I needed out of the box!